Remove empty tags from XML using XSLT except whitespaces
I wish to remove all the blank tags from my xml using xslt, except when a tag contains a whitespace.Also there should be no impact on line breaks etc. The xml should be copied as is, except for the blank tags with no value or whitespace.
Source XML
<inRoot>
    <t1></t1>
    <t2> </t2>
    <t3>World</t3>
</inRoot>

Output I want
<inRoot>
    <t2> </t2>
    <t3>World</t3>
</inRoot>

XSLT I tried is removing t1 but is giving me a blank line in place of t1.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements=""/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
            <xsl:if test=".!=''">
                <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                  <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

This code gives me output as
<inRoot>
    
    <t2> </t2>
    <t3>World</t3>
</inRoot>

Could anyone please advise why I am getting this extra line for t1.
Regards

Did you have a chance to try the proposed solutions?

Use the identity transformation template (in XSLT 1 and 2) or declare (in XSLT 3) <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/> plus the template
<xsl:template match="*[not(node())]"/>

to ensure that element nodes not having any contents/any child nodes are not copied through.

As @MartinHonnen pointed out, it is better to use a so called Identity Transform pattern.
Also, I had to specify additional setting via:
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:preserve-space elements="t1 t2 t3"/>

Input XML
<inRoot>
    <t1></t1>
    <t2> </t2>
    <t3>World</t3>
</inRoot>

XSLT 2.0
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
                encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:preserve-space elements="t1 t2 t3"/>

    <!--Identity transform-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(node())]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output XML
<inRoot>
  <t2> </t2>
  <t3>World</t3>
</inRoot>


This makes no sense. OP asked to remove all empty elements, excluding elements that contain whitespace only. By doing <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> such distinction becomes impossible. You then make an exception by adding <xsl:preserve-space elements="t1 t2 t3"/> but this applies only to the named elements. The correct solution is to simply remove both of these instructions.

@michael.hor257k,  Without them there are empty lines in the output. I am using Saxon 9.7.0.15


why I am getting this extra line for t1.

You are getting an extra line because you have conflicting requirements:

On the one hand, you want to keep any element that contains only
whitespace. For this, you need to avoid stripping whitespace from the
input XML.

On the other hand, you want to remove the line breaks that occur
before and after a removed element. These line breaks are part of the whitespace text nodes of the parent element.


In most cases, whitespace in XML is insignificant and you can just live with it. If you really want to get rid of (some of) it, you will need to make some kind of compromise.  In the given example, you could do:
XSLT 2.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="inRoot"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(node())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>

However, this means you need to know in advance the name of the root element of the input XML. And if that element contains only whitespace, it will be removed despite your first requirement.
And it won't work for a differently structured XML input where the removed elements are not children of the root element but one of its descendants.


The xml should be copied as is, except for the blank tags with no value or whitespace.

Well, that's not what your example does. Your example removes what you call a "blank tag" (correctly, an empty element) together with the whitespace text node that precedes it.
You could do that with an identity transform plus the two rules:
<xsl:template match="*[not(node())]"/>
<xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())][following-sibling::*[1][not(node())]]"/>

Whether you would find the result pleasing for other examples is something that only you can tell.
